# F# Quotation from string

Tags: f#

In F# the following code is legal:

```
let q = <@ fun a b -> a + b @>
let f = QuotationEvaluator.Evaluate(q)
let c = f 1 3
```

Is there a way to start from a string instead?

```
let s = "<@ fun a b -> a + b @>"
let q = Expr.Parse(s) //How?
let f = QuotationEvaluator.Evaluate(q)
let c = f 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, there is no way to parse a string to a quotation expression.